# How can I use .EntireRow but skip column A?

Tags: vba, excel

Looking for either a workaround or some idea on how I can use the code excerpt below, but skip column A.

Basically, I'm using

```
.EntireRow(a.Row).Interior.Color = color
```

to highlight rows based on a userform selection, but I need to skip column A as it has headers that have their own highlighting.

Any ideas?

```
If ToggleButton3.Value = True Then
    On Error Resume Next
    For iRow = 1 To 15
    If Sheets("Prop" & iRow).Visible <> xlSheetVisible Then
    Else
        With Sheets("Prop" & iRow).Range("$E$1:$E$157")
            Set a = .Find(SlctdPAX, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
            .EntireRow(a.Row).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 102) 'yellow
        End With
    End If
    Next iRow
ElseIf ToggleButton1.Value = True Then
    On Error Resume Next
    For iRow = 1 To 15
    If Sheets("Prop" & iRow).Visible <> xlSheetVisible Then
    Else
        With Sheets("Prop" & iRow).Range("$E$1:$E$157")
            Set a = .Find(SlctdPAX, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
            .EntireRow(a.Row).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) 'red
        End With
    End If
    Next iRow
ElseIf ToggleButton4.Value = True Then
    On Error Resume Next
    For iRow = 1 To 15
    If Sheets("Prop" & iRow).Visible <> xlSheetVisible Then
    Else
        With Sheets("Prop" & iRow).Range("$E$1:$E$157")
            Set a = .Find(SlctdPAX, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
            .EntireRow(a.Row).Interior.Color = xlNone 'no fill
        End With
    End If
    Next iRow
ElseIf ToggleButton2.Value = True Then
    On Error Resume Next
    For iRow = 1 To 15
    If Sheets("Prop" & iRow).Visible <> xlSheetVisible Then
    Else
        With Sheets("Prop" & iRow).Range("$E$1:$E$157")
            Set a = .Find(SlctdPAX, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
            .EntireRow(a.Row).Interior.Color = RGB(128, 255, 0) 'green
        End With
    End If
    Next iRow
Else
End If
```

Comment: `.Range(.Cells(a.Row,2),.Cells(a.Row,16384)) .Interior.Color = color`

Comment: @ScottCraner - using `.Columns.Count` instead of `16384` would make it work across older XL platforms (or if the increase the columns in the future). Small point, but makes the code more sustainable.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman, you are, of course, correct.  I was not thinking.

Comment: Why not just execute a `remove formatting` for column A after you use the entirerow command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets say `a` is a single cell.

With regards to exclude highlighting column A,

- to highlight entire row of `a`, do:

  `a.EntireRow.Resize(, Columns.Count - 1).Offset(, 1).Interior.Color`
- to highlight multiple rows staked together below `a`, e.g. 5 rows, do:

  `a.EntireRow.Resize(5, Columns.Count - 1).Offset(, 1).Interior.Color`
- to highlight multiple rows which are not staked together, e.g. entire rows of [E1], [E3], [E5], do:

  `Intersect(Union([E1], [E3], [E5]).EntireRow, Cells.Resize(, Columns.Count - 1).Offset(, 1))`

FYI, just tested that `Union([E1], [E3], [E5]).EntireRow.Resize()` is not allowed.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I like this answer the best as it captures the whole row.

Comment: I added an edit that isn't approved yet. Specifically it addresses the need to add the 'number of rows to hightlight' and 'which row to highlight' before each of the commas within .Resize

Comment: You're welcome. Are you needing that multiples rows which are not joint together to be highlighted ?

Comment: i just updated the answer, let me know if u hv any questions. its late here, i'll come back to u tomoro,

Answer (score 2):

```
        With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Prop" & iRow)
            Set a = .Range("$E$1:$E$157").Find(SlctdPAX, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
            a.EntireRow.Resize(1, .Cells(a.row, .Columns.Count - 1).column).Offset(, 1).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) 'red
        End With
```

which is quite much whar KS Sheon has already posted.

but I'm afraid his code, being inside `With Sheets("Prop" & iRow).Range("$E$1:$E$157")` block , would color all rows from 1 to 157.

moreover `Columns.Count` would count the number of columns of the active sheet, which may not be the one wanted